# How to invoke a method taking String * with elements of Array[String]

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a method

```
def f(s:String *) = s.foreach( x => println(x) )
```

Now I have an array:

```
val a = Array("1", "2", "3")
```

How do I invoke `f` with elements of `a` as parameters?

EDIT:

So given `a`, I want to do the following:

```
f(a(0), a(1), a(2))  // f("1", "2", "3")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an operator for that:

```
f(a: _*)
```

This operation is defined in chapter *4.6.2 Repeated Parameters* of [The Scala Language Specification Version 2.9](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) and further explained in *6.6 Function Applications*:

> The last argument in an application may be marked as a sequence argument, e.g.
>   **`e : _*`**. Such an argument must correspond to a repeated parameter (§4.6.2) of type
>   `S *` [...]. Furthermore, the **type of e must conform to `scala.Seq[T]`, for some type `T` which conforms to `S`**. In this
>   case, the argument list is transformed by replacing the sequence e with its elements.

---

BTW your `f` function can be simplified:

```
def f(s:String *) = s foreach println
```

Or better (equals sign is discouraged as it suggests that the method actually returns something, however it "only" return `Unit`):

```
def f(s:String *) {s foreach println}
```

Comment: I quoted Scala spec to address your concerns. This is basically a language construct built into the compiler. Groovy has a similar operator: f(*a).